# Getting 'AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup' in python code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have imported bs4 as such
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`. Here is the part where I initialize beautiful soup in my code:

```
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
```

When I run my script via bash, I get the following error:

```
16:27 ~ $ python2.7 toptickerbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toptickerbot.py", line 332, in <module>
    result()
  File "toptickerbot.py", line 209, in result
    data = scandata(30000000, 200000000, -0.99, 0.99, 0, 25)
  File "toptickerbot.py", line 149, in scandata
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
  File "toptickerbot.py", line 26, in save_sp500_tickers
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'
```

Not sure what the attribute error is referring to. Also, when I run my code in an jupyter notebook it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the `as bs` part, your code will be equivalent to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
```

And the error message says that `BeautifulSoup` has no attribute `BeautifulSoup`.

Did you mean this?

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
```

Or maybe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(resp.text)
```